# Can I wire both a 50 amp hot tub and 50 amp RV plug in the same box?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, gfci, hot-tub

I have two projects in the works, installing a hot tub and building an RV pad. Both the RV and hot tub run on 50 amps and 220 volts. RV's plug-in but hot tubs are wired directly. Is there a single GFCI box that can accommodate both or do I need a subpanel and a GFCI box? Can all of this run in a single conduit?

They both sit around a corner from each other. I would route the conduit 5 ft from the tub in line of sight.

I will not be performing the electrical hook up myself but I do want to save some money and dig the trench and lay conduit before laying pavers for the RV pad.

I've included links to a few pictures of my main outside panel to make sure my box can even handle this. My individual breakers for the house are in an inside panel. Thank you!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your electrical service capacity from the utility?? 100A? 125A?  I can read the 100 number on your main breaker, that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: With your main disconnect only being rated for 125 amps that doesn’t leave much room for new circuits, if your home has gas appliances and heating you might have enough to do it but we need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Most people in the general population seem to believe that the size of the breaker indicates the size of the load, but that's nor true. Breakers (overcurrent protection) are installed to protect the circuit. We don't know the actual load of your RV. We only know that one of the standard feeders for an RV is 50A, but if yo are just parking it and the only thing running in it is the refrigerator and the water heater. Then what's the load? Or are you using it to park an RV for someone to live in/ Then what's the load? Are you going to be using the hot tub and the RV at the same time? Once again what's the load? It appears you are using this panel to handle a current feeder of 100A. What's its current load?

So you can see that we really can't answer the basic question of whether or not the service to the panel can actually operate since we need addition information about your entire dwelling. Can you add 2 - 50A/2P breakers into the existing panel? It looks like you can, but the photos don't even show if you have a ground and it doesn't show that you have a neutral. Are you going to have any 120V load? **Also it shows your line in was attached to your bus by drilling two holes in the side of the panel.** **This is a very dangerous situation** since the current carrying conductors are not bundled and this is causing mutual induction in the panel itself. This can cause electrical shock and potential melting of the insulation of the conductors.

In short you are wise to get an electrical contractor on your project as soon as possible and let him work the through the details before you start your projects

Good luck.

Comment: Looking at the panel's labeling, I'm not sure those are actually installer-drilled holes in the side -- I believe those conductors are factory installed to connect to the meter half of the combination meter-main panel.  And from the labeling, there should also be a neutral somewhere in a box to the right of this section.

Comment: Yeah, if you look at the diagram of that panel, those holes in the barrier were factory-made to accommodate the wiring from the meter socket to the LC interior